# How can I backup Ubuntu's "config"? A list of my extra installed stuff, as a script if possible?

Tags: backup, data-recovery

I have crashes often cause of computer problems, and have to reinstall everything every few weeks. What would be useful is a script that can keep track of what I install, that I carry around to my new boots.

Comment: Consider the tool timeshift, backing up the system files to a separate drive. If the computer breaks, reinstall fresh then restore the latest snapshot which will put all your extra programs and configuration back.

Comment: There only single tool that will keep track of EVERYTHING you installed is the human brain. There is no current software that will do it -- you must keep notes. If you decide to create such a tool to keep track of deb, snaps, pip wheels, tarballs, compiled source, brews, AppImages, flatpaks, and all the others, please consider contributing it to Debian (from whence it will sync to Ubuntu) so your effort helps the entire community.

Comment: I include this in my backup script. `sudo apt-mark showmanual | sort -u > somefile` My somefile also has date & sub-folder where I store my lists of files. You still may need to manually edit out old kernels & anything you do not want in a new install. You also can export all apps and compare with the default manifest of installed files which ever install has. `comm -23 <( dpkg --get-selections | awk '$2 ~ /^(install|hold)/ { print $1 }' | sort ) \
  <( awk '{ print $1 }' ubuntu-22.04-desktop-amd64.manifest | sort )`

Comment: you may find [this reference](https://www.howtogeek.com/810903/linux-list-installed-packages/) useful in listing installed packages.